# Sencha Touch: After scrolling a panel using a button tap it back to initial position again when scroll end

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to scroll a panel using button tap, and the panel is scrolling as I want. But my problem is that,

**After scroll end it back again to its initial position, doesn't stick to its new position**.

Why this behavior and how can I get leave from this?

**Code I used** *(working just fine)*

```
var container = this.getDealdetails();
container.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(x , y, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

The scrollable container will scroll back if the scroll to position is greater than the height of the container.

This is best demonstrated with an example. Run this fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#8Qnt8

Make your browser window smaller in height and note how it behaves. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your answer was useful for me

Answer (score 1):

```
var panel= Ext.getCmp('iObserveCreateRecords');
panel.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollTo(0, 0, true);
```

//iObserveCreateRecords is panel id